# Why does iOS crash when attempting to display sort results in reverse order?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI app that displays information by section. When a button is pressed, I want to sort both the section headers as well as the content of each section either ascending or descending (i.e., the button reverses the current sort order.

When the button is pressed, the app crashes immediately with the following error.  I've simplified the code to easily reproduce the problem.  In the real app, the app does not crash unless you scroll the data and then sort.

How can I achieve the desired result without the crash?  Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

```
Catalina 10.15.2
Xcode 11.3
iOS 13.3
```

```
2020-01-29 22:31:07.837639-0800 sections[33051:9858192] *** Assertion failure in -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _setupAnimationsForNewlyInsertedCells], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore_Sim/UIKit-3901.4.2/UITableViewSupport.m:1311
2020-01-29 22:31:07.847803-0800 sections[33051:9858192] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempt to create two animations for cell'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c7127e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff513fbb20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c70ff8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 88
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff256e9b51 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 191
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff482c3979 -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport(Private) _setupAnimationsForNewlyInsertedCells] + 1575
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff482ce773 -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _setupAnimations] + 118
    6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48265026 -[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:] + 2892
    7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4825cfd4 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 17188
    8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48276e0b -[UITableView endUpdatesWithContext:] + 112
    9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48276fb7 -[UITableView _performBatchUpdates:withContext:completion:] + 253
    10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff482770cf -[UITableView performBatchUpdates:completion:] + 98
    11  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c24ea26 $s7SwiftUI25UpdateCoalescingTableView33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A49LLC19performBatchUpdates_10completionyyycSg_ySbcSgtF + 470
    12  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c24ebaf $s7SwiftUI25UpdateCoalescingTableView33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A49LLC19performBatchUpdates_10completionyyycSg_ySbcSgtFTo + 175
    13  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c2510cc $s7SwiftUI19ListCoreCoordinator33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A49LLC17updateUITableView_4from2toySo0mN0C_xxtF + 1692
    14  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c24f9ed $s7SwiftUI9_ListCore33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A49LLV12updateUIView_7contextyAA12TableWrapperACLLC_AA0L20RepresentableContextVyADyxq_GGtF + 973
    15  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c6149c1 $s7SwiftUI32PlatformViewRepresentableAdaptor33_19642D833A8FE469B137699ED1426762LLV06updateD8Provider_7contexty10UIViewTypeQz_AA0cdE7ContextVyADyxGGtF + 289
    16  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c2c6afb $s7SwiftUI17PlatformViewChild33_A513612C07DFA438E70B9FA90719B40DLLV6update7contexty14AttributeGraph0O7ContextVyADyxGGz_tFyyXEfU_ + 2315
    17  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c2c07f6 $s7SwiftUI17PlatformViewChild33_A513612C07DFA438E70B9FA90719B40DLLV6update7contexty14AttributeGraph0O7ContextVyADyxGGz_tF + 310
    18  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c2c7e60 $s7SwiftUI17PlatformViewChild33_A513612C07DFA438E70B9FA90719B40DLLVyxG14AttributeGraph07UntypedM0AafGP7_update_5graph9attributeySv_So10AGGraphRefaSo11AGAttributeatFZTW + 32
    19  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff2f8c0c69 $sTA + 25
    20  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff2f8a8ac5 _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 1111
    21  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff2f8a8d83 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeEjb + 377
    22  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff2f8ad9a1 _ZN2AG8Subgraph6updateEj + 929
    23  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c180405 $s7SwiftUI9ViewGraphC13updateWrapperyyyyXEcvgyyyXEcfU_yACXEfU_ + 53
    24  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c185c11 $s7SwiftUI9ViewGraphCIgg_ACytIeggr_TRTA + 17
    25  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c4cbdd7 $s7SwiftUI16ViewRendererHostPAAE06updateC5Graph4bodyqd__qd__AA0cG0CXE_tlF + 71
    26  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c4cbd83 $s7SwiftUI14_UIHostingViewCyqd__GAA0D13GraphDelegateA2aEP06updatedE04bodyqd__qd__AA0dE0CXE_tlFTW + 19
    27  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c1803a5 $s7SwiftUI9ViewGraphC13updateWrapperyyyyXEcvgyyyXEcfU_ + 181
    28  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff2f8ad890 _ZN2AG8Subgraph6updateEj + 656
    29  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c1826c0 $s7SwiftUI9ViewGraphC14runTransaction33_D63C4EB7F2B205694B6515509E76E98BLL2inySo10AGGraphRefa_tF + 224
    30  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c182490 $s7SwiftUI9ViewGraphC17flushTransactionsyyFySo10AGGraphRefaXEfU_ + 256
    31  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c18212f $s7SwiftUI9ViewGraphC17flushTransactionsyyF + 223
    32  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c1822af $s7SwiftUI9ViewGraphC16asyncTransaction_8mutation5styleyAA0F0V_xAA01_D14Mutation_StyleOtAA0dI0RzlFyycfU_yACXEfU_ + 15
    33  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c180439 $s7SwiftUI9ViewGraphCIgg_ACytIeggr_TR03$s7a3UI9cD92C16asyncTransaction_8mutation5styleyAA0F0V_xAA01_D14Mutation_StyleOtAA0dI0RzlFyycfU_yACXEfU_Tf3nnpf_n + 9
    34  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c4cbdd7 $s7SwiftUI16ViewRendererHostPAAE06updateC5Graph4bodyqd__qd__AA0cG0CXE_tlF + 71
    35  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c4cbd83 $s7SwiftUI14_UIHostingViewCyqd__GAA0D13GraphDelegateA2aEP06updatedE04bodyqd__qd__AA0dE0CXE_tlFTW + 19
    36  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c18228a $s7SwiftUI9ViewGraphC16asyncTransaction_8mutation5styleyAA0F0V_xAA01_D14Mutation_StyleOtAA0dI0RzlFyycfU_ + 122
    37  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c1a078c $sIeg_ytIegr_TR + 12
    38  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2bfe3261 $sIeg_ytIegr_TRTA + 17
    39  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2bfe3187 $sSo9NSRunLoopC7SwiftUIE14flushObserversyyFZ + 119
    40  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2bfe3109 $sSo9NSRunLoopC7SwiftUIE11addObserveryyyycFZySo05CFRunbF3RefaSg_So0gB8ActivityVSvSgtcfU_ + 9
    41  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2bfe31fb $sSo9NSRunLoopC7SwiftUIE11addObserveryyyycFZySo05CFRunbF3RefaSg_So0gB8ActivityVSvSgtcfU_To + 43
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bd3867 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    43  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bce2fe __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
    44  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bce97a __CFRunLoopRun + 1514
    45  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bce066 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
    46  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff384c0bb0 GSEventRunModal + 65
    47  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48092d4d UIApplicationMain + 1621
    48  sections                            0x000000010af50bbb main + 75
    49  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff5227ec25 start + 1
    50  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  sections
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var ascending: Bool = true

    var body: some View {


               VStack {
                   Button(action: {
                       self.ascending.toggle()
                   }) {
                       if self.ascending {
                           Text("Sort Descending")
                       } else {
                           Text("Sort Ascending")
                       }
                   }

                   SectionView(boats: [Boat(name: "B1", number: "1"),
                                       Boat(name: "B2", number: "2"),
                                       Boat(name: "B3", number: "3"),
                                       Boat(name: "B22", number: "22"),
                                       Boat(name: "B24", number: "24"),
                                       Boat(name: "B333", number: "333"),
                                       Boat(name: "B4", number: "3"),
                                       Boat(name: "B5", number: "3"),

                   ], ascending: ascending)
               }
           }
       }

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

```
//
//  SectionView.swift
//  sections
//


import SwiftUI

struct Boat: Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var number: String
}

struct SectionView: View {

    var boats = [Boat]()
    var ascending: Bool

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach (self.classDictionary(ascending: ascending), id: \.0) { key, boats in
                    Section(header: Text("\(key)").font(.caption).bold()) {

                        ForEach (boats, id: \.self) { boat in
                            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(boat: boat)) {
                                Text(boat.name)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //
    func classDictionary(ascending: Bool) ->  [(key: String, boats: [Boat])] {

        var returnTuple = [(key: String, boats: [Boat])]()

        let groupedDictionary = Dictionary(grouping: self.boats, by: {String(numberOfDigits(in: Int($0.number)!))})

        for (key, boats) in groupedDictionary {
            returnTuple.append((key, boats))
        }

        if ascending {
            returnTuple = returnTuple.sorted(by: { $0.boats.map { Int($0.number)!}.min() ?? 0 < $1.boats.map { Int($0.number)!}.min() ?? 0 })
        } else {
            returnTuple = returnTuple.sorted(by: { $0.boats.map { Int($0.number)!}.max() ?? 0 > $1.boats.map { Int($0.number)!}.max() ?? 0 })
        }

        return returnTuple
    }

    // private recursive method for counting digits
    private func numberOfDigits(in number: Int) -> Int {
        if number < 10 && number >= 0 || number > -10 && number < 0 {
            return 1
        } else {
            return 1 + numberOfDigits(in: number/10)
        }
    }
}



struct SectionView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var ascending: Bool = true

    static var previews: some View {

        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.ascending.toggle()
            }) {
                if self.ascending {
                    Text("Sort Descending")
                } else {
                    Text("Sort Ascending")
                }
                //                Text("Change Sort")
            }

            SectionView(boats: [Boat(name: "B1", number: "1"),
                                Boat(name: "B2", number: "2"),
                                Boat(name: "B3", number: "3"),
                                Boat(name: "B22", number: "22"),
                                Boat(name: "B24", number: "24"),
                                Boat(name: "B333", number: "333"),
                                Boat(name: "B4", number: "3"),
                                Boat(name: "B5", number: "3"),

            ], ascending: ascending)
        }
    }
}


struct DetailView: View {

    var boat: Boat

    var body: some View {
        Text(boat.name)
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to do your data to an "@observable" instead of internal data? normally you should put all data which changes to "@State" or "@published/observable"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The origin of issue is in content identifiers... so changing the following lines fix the crash

1)

```
ForEach (self.classDictionary(ascending: ascending), id: \.1) { key, boats in
```

Note: For performance purpose I would recommend instead to create explicit struct for Section data with usage own UUID as id.

2)

```
ForEach (boats, id: \.id) { boat in
```